# MCP73831T STAT pin always high

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, charger

Good day, I have purchased the following charge management controller:

**[MCP73831T-2ACI/OTCT-ND](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001984g.pdf)**

I'm using the following diagram:

[image]

But, the LED (**D1**) never lights up, with or without battery. When measured, the STAT pin is always 3.7V, and the VBAT pin, is always at the same voltage of the Battery.

I'm using ceramic SMD capacitors for C1 and C2, and SMD resistors for R1 and R2. Both, capacitors and resistors, are 0805.

Measurements, with battery:

```
VBUS = 5.1V
VBAT = 4.0V (Current battery voltage)
STAT = 3.7V
PROG = 3.54V
VSS =  0.0V
```

Measurements, without battery:

```
VBUS = 5.1V
VBAT = 0.0V (See note 1)
STAT = 3.7V
PROG = 3.54V
VSS =  0.0V
```

I have also removed the PCM circuit from the battery, but it did not work. 
The battery is labeled as 3.7V 700mAh, DS 902540.

1. *When the battery is disconnected, the VBAT voltage starts decreasing from 4.0V to 0.0V, slowly. Is this normal?*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about a hyperlink to the chip.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have figured It out. The R2 resistor, was not properly soldered. When measuring with the multimeter, the contact seemed to be fine, but In certain moment, I made some pressure on the resistors and the LED turned on. So I resoldered it and tested again. Now, the VBAT voltage is increasing from 3.7V, and the battery is charging.